# UIWebView still exist in Google Mobile Ads

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiwebview, app-store-connect, wkwebview

I am trying to build for IOS but after uploading to ITuneconnect I got this message.
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

I know this problem exists already. I searched my Project using this command

grep -r "UIWebView".

I got one match

Binary file ./GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds matches

Please let me know how can I solve this problem.

Anyone have a solution then, please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the version of Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK ?

Comment: I tried version 7.61.0 and latest version 7.9.1 but both used UIWebview.

Comment: Please show me, How are you installing pod for Google Ads.

Comment: 1.In pod file i define pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' then install pod using 'pod install' command that time install below pods
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.61.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.6.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.6.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.9)
Installing nanopb (1.30905.0)

2.In pod file i define pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK','~>7.9.1' then install Pod using 'pod install' command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Alright!**

So Install your Google Ads pod with put this line **pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'**

And don't worry about `grep -r "UIWebView" .` It will show UIWebView in Google Ads,

But It will not stop you from Build your app and submit to TestFlight/App Store,

Because Google has fixed this.

**Points:**

- Clear your derived data `(/Users/yourMacName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/)`
- Clean Xcode project  `(cmd+shift+k)`

Comment: Even though the release notes mention that UIWebview has been removed the references are still there and it still triggers the warning from Apple

Comment: Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.65.0, Xcode 11.5 works for me. When I run `grep -r "UIWebView" .` it still shows warning but Apple accepts it.

Comment: Hi @¡Developer I have tried your solution and Apple keeps rejecting my project. **UIWebView are no longer acceptedCan** you give me any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: @MiguelEspeso please check in your project for **grep -r "UIWebView" .** Is there anything else remaining of UIWebView in your whole project.

Comment: @¡Developer I don't know in which folder I should run this command. look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444970/apple-does-not-accept-apps-that-use-uiwebview)

Comment: Still same issue and apple started rejecting binary itself.

Comment: Any update for this? I am using the version 7.69.0

Comment: @sejn Please check, If you are using uiwebview in your project apart from Google Ad Mob.

Comment: Yes I am using the UIWebView and updated most of the dependencies. But while doing the grep it shows the below two files. GoogleAdMobAdsSDK/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds

GoogleAdMobAdsSDK/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds