# Deprecated API Usage - App updates that use UIWebView will no longer be accepted

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I've followed the suggestions on this topic but I still can't get rid of the UIWebView

list of my pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK','7.65.0'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics' 
pod 'Chartbeat', '1.4.1' ######
pod 'TaboolaSDK', '2.8.0'
pod 'FacebookCore', '0.9.0'
pod 'FacebookShare', '0.9.0'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '0.9.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '5.15.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '5.15.1' 
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '5.15.1'
pod 'TwitterKit', '3.4.2'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '5.0.2'
pod 'WKJavaScriptController'
pod 'AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout'
pod 'JWPlayer-SDK', '3.17.0'
pod 'PianoComposer', '~>2.3.8'
```

all firebase pods are updated. when i grep for UIWebView i get:

```
grep: ./ArtiPlayer.framework/Resources: No such file or directory
./Pods/AppAuth/README.md:for the auth request. `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are explicitly.  
*not*
Binary file ./Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework- 
Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds matches 
Binary file ./Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit matches
./Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/Headers/TWTRTweet.h: *  Suitable for loading in a 
`UIWebView`, `WKWebView` or passing to Safari:
./Pods/GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching.  
to a browser,
grep: ./ArtiSDK.framework/Resources: No such file or directory
```

GoogleMobileAds, TwitterKit and GoogleSignIn are updated to latest version.
please help

Comment: **pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK','7.65.0'** This might be the issue. See this -


  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462490/uiwebview-still-exist-in-google-mobile-ads/63468440?noredirect=1#comment113139420_63468440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the latest version of TwitterKit, but it uses `UIWebView` and it is [no longer supported by Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html) so it won't be updated to remove the use of `UIWebView`.

You will need to find some other way of providing that functionality in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I have an out of date Google framework that uses `UIWebView`, but the app code doesn't call anything that actually uses it.

I found an open source binary editor, [bbe](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bbe), that works much like sed. I used it to replace the string `UIWebView` with `WKWebView`, and since then any submission to the app store goes through just fine with no warning.

Obviously, it your code causes the framework to instantiate a `WKWebView`, it's going to crash for sure - so YMMV.

PS: I used `bbe` to search for the string `UIWebView` in all my binary frameworks to first find the offending one - it wasn't immediately obvious which one used it.

Comment: https://github.com/touren/twitter-kit-ios/releases/tag/v5.2.0

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps. This may be useful.

a) Comment all the pods

b) Install pods `pod install` - This would remove all pod files

c) Uncomment and remove the version that you have mentioned on each of the pod.

d) Install pods - This would install freshly

e) Now clean `Shift + command + k`