# Apple does not accept apps that use UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, uiwebview, google-mobile-ads

I have a game created in Unity which Apple does not accept because of the following:

It seems that the problem is in Google Mobile ADS

**We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "My Game" 10.0 (10). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).**

I have followed several answer that I found on stackoverflow:

[UIWebView still exist in Google Mobile Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462490/uiwebview-still-exist-in-google-mobile-ads)

I have also followed other Unity forums and I can't find a solution

https://forum.unity.com/threads/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-new-apps-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer-accepted.883510/

My game is created with Unity, and at no time have I used Pod

I have run `grep -r "UIWebView".` , but this shows files that I can't see, not in xCode, and not in Visual Studio either

I don't know exactly in which folder I should run this command. When I do it in the Pod folder, it shows me files that I cannot open in the editorHow can I find where the files containing UIWebView are located?

I don't know how to find those files in xCode to modify them and try to get Apple to accept my game

Can you help me find those files in xCode?
What should i do to correct this problem?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
I need answers that solve my problem. The only answer there is, except for mine, offers data that I have tried and showed in my question. I do not see logical that the reward is given to someone who has not read my question, Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you import the right version of the library? Google Ads says UIWebView is removed from version 7.55 (https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes). Grep can find UIWebView in the files also if it's not a problem for the AppStore. You should check the Google Ads SDK version loaded in the app. If Unity uses Cocoapods you should see the loaded version in a file called "Podfile.lock"

Comment: I am using iOS 7.68.0 SDK. But I don't know where the problem is @AlexB

Comment: As said grep can fine the text "UIWebView" in your lib also if it's not actually used (it can be just a comment). Google says that the problem is fixed from 7.55 so probably your issue comes from something other. Try to clean caches, derived data on Xcode, rebuild again the app (being sure you import the 7.68 sdk) and resubmit to the AppStore. Maybe it fixes the problem. For sure you can't fix it manually in the code. They said it fixed so the problem can be you import wrong version of the lib or elsewhere. IMO.

Comment: Thanks @AlexB I've already tried that and I can't discover the files. I have gotten another solution, since nobody offers something better, I have answered my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally and seeing that I do not receive a response, I have solved the problem by starting the project again in the Unity 2020.1.17f1 version.
This is not really a solution to the problem that I raised, but since it has solved my problem, I put it as an answer.
Thanks to those who have tried to help me. @AlexB

Answer (score 0):

I have to say you can add WebKit.framework at UnityFramework > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries. Then After Update pods from terminal and upload project and apple approved game.

It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

open terminal on macos and try :

`grep -Ril "UIWebView" "/Users/yourUserName/yourProjectFolder"`

Comment: Thanks @Trojan-X . I've already tried that and I can't discover the files. I have gotten another solution as no one offers better